# Convert Angle and Speed into 3d Vector in Python

Tags: python, vector, 3d, blender, angle

I am programming some controls for a spaceship simulator and am using an impulse function that takes a given `x,y,z` point and an impulse vector, and moves an object accordingly.

I am having trouble figuring out how to convert a given input speed and orientation in `3d` space (eulers or quaternions) with python. I understand how to do this on a 2d plane, but with the addition of a third dimension I'm stumped.

I am using the blender game engine, which is a python based system.

Bonus points if you include how to actually calculate an impulse vector as well as with a given mass!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just poking around with google I managed to find this page: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_0/mathutils.html

If you're using Euler rotation scheme the mathutils.Euler object looks useful.  If you're using Quaternions, then mathutils.Quaternion is what you need.

The next step is to convert whatever rotation scheme you're using into a Matrix, and then pick the proper column (or row, I'm not sure if blender uses the x'=xM or x'=Mx convention) corresponding to the forward axis (is the front of your rocket in the X, Y, or Z direction?)